# How to know if setroubleshoot is running in Centos 7.2

Tags: selinux

I have tried `systemctl status setroubleshootd.service`, but I get

```
● setroubleshootd.service
Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
Active: inactive (dead)
```

Neither does setroubleshootd appear in the output of `ps ax`.

However, `yum info setroubleshoot`, tells that the package is installed.

```
Installed Packages
Name        : setroubleshoot
Arch        : x86_64
Version     : 3.2.24
Release     : 1.1.el7
Size        : 235 k
Repo        : installed
From repo   : anaconda
```

In the same way, `yum info setroubleshoot-server` tells that such package is also installed.

So, it seems to be installed, but not recognized by systemd. How can I see whether it is running or not?  And, if it is not running, how to enable it?

Comment: Have you tried: "ps -ef | grep -i setroubleshoot" ?

Answer (score 8):

Found it. The problem is that `setroubleshootd` does not run permanently in CentOS 7.  It is started only when an AVC denial message reaches `auditd`.  This is confusing, since you normally expect a daemon to constantly run in the background.

See: [SELinux User's and Administrator's Guide: Which Log File is Used](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/selinux_users_and_administrators_guide/sect-security-enhanced_linux-working_with_selinux-which_log_file_is_used)

Comment: The sequence seems to be: kernel signals `auditd`, which invokes `audispd`, which invokes `sedispatch` (as configured in `/etc/audisp/plugins.d/sedispatch.conf`), which formats the SELinux AVC record and sends a DBUS message to DBUS, which starts `setroubleshootd` under user "setroubleshoot" if it is not running. `setroubleshootd` receives the DBUS message, formats/preprocesses according to plugins, emits a syslog message which by default ends up in `/var/log/messages` and signals (via DBUS) interested client programs like `sealert` that something is up.